# How to create b3dm from kml or json

Tags: json, gis, kml

What is the process of making `b3dm` files from the `kml` or `json` file?

I want to use https://cesiumjs.org, it used b3dm files but i have kml and json.

I found [3D Tiles Tools](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/3d-tiles-tools/tree/master/tools) that convert glb to b3dm, is there any way to convert kml to b3dm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a little bit and I found this conversation on Google.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/3tCx3CkL-3U

This Guy goes from kml to gltf to glb to b3dm. He had a problem with falty b3dm data.

Maybe this will help you aswell.

Greetings Doggo

Comment: What is the Status of your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I must test `3DCityDB` at the first.